# Why is my meteor server method not called from the client to delete a document?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to learn a little bite of Meteor. This is my event on the client side:

```
Template.todos_list.events({
    'click .todo-done': function () {
      console.log(this);
      Meteor.call('updateToDo', this._id, !this.completed);
    },
      'click .single-delete': function () {
        Meteor.call('singleDelete');
        //Todos.remove(this._id); **<-- this works when insecure is activated** 
        console.log('clicked the ' + this._id)
      }
  });
```

Server Side:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addTodo: function (title) {
      Todos.insert({
        title: title,
        completed: false
      })
    },
    singleDelete: function() {
      Todos.remove({_id: this._id});
    }
  });
```

I also tried just to use Todos.remove(this._id) at the server side but it doesn't work, either. It somehow only works on the client side.

What am I missing?

Thanks to all of you,
Amir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yo have to pass the _id of your object to your singleDelete function.

Changes on client Side:

```
Meteor.call('singleDelete', this._id);
```

and the changes on server Side:

```
singleDelete: function(todoId) {
  Todos.remove({_id: todoId});
}
```

// Edit: I've added a short link to the Javascript this behavior:
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/javascript-for-meteor search for 'This'

> Basically, the this keyword lets you access the object on which you’re currently working: just like a chameleon, this keeps changing based on its surroundings.

// Edit2: Another great reference: http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

> How `this` Works
>
> JavaScript has a different concept of what the special name this refers to than most other programming languages. There are exactly five different ways in which the value of this can be bound in the language.